# Two animations in CSS not working at the same time

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I've created two animations with CSS a clock and a bouncing ball. Separately they both work as intended, but once I put them in the same file the bouncing ball disappeared.

If I delete `@keyframes rotation` the clock stops working but the bouncing ball appears. Is there any way how to make both animations work?

```css
.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 2px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 20px 199px;
  animation: rotation 60s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#minute {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 6px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 60px 197px;
  animation: rotation 3600s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

#hour {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 80px 195px;
  animation: rotation 43200s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

  @keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }

.box {
  position: relative;
}
.ball {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  background: pink;
  
  }

.step1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;
}

  .step2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 220px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;  
}

.step3 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 440px;
  top: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;
}

@keyframes bounce {
     from {margin: 100pxz 0px;} 
    to{margin: 50px 500px;} 
    0% {
        transform: translateY(-30%);
    }

    12% {
        transform: translateY(33%);
    }

    24% {
        transform: translateY(-66%);
    }

   36% {
        transform: translateY(33%);
    }

    48% {
        transform: translateY(-20%);
    }
  
    100% {
        transform: translateY(33%);
  }
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div id="hour"></div>
  <div id="minute"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="step1"></div>
  <div class="step2"></div>
  <div class="step3"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, you're/were missing the closing brackets on your keyframes

```css
.clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#second {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 2px;
  height: 180px;
  margin: 20px 199px;
  animation: rotation 60s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

#minute {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 6px;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 60px 197px;
  animation: rotation 3600s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
}

#hour {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  width: 10px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 80px 195px;
  animation: rotation 43200s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

.box {
  position: relative;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 3px solid pink;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite;
  background: pink;
}

.step1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;
}

.step2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 220px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;
}

.step3 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 440px;
  top: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  background: cyan;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  from {
    margin: 100pxz 0px;
  }
  to {
    margin: 50px 500px;
  }
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-30%);
  }
  12% {
    transform: translateY(33%);
  }
  24% {
    transform: translateY(-66%);
  }
  36% {
    transform: translateY(33%);
  }
  48% {
    transform: translateY(-20%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(33%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div id="hour"></div>
  <div id="minute"></div>
  <div id="second"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="step1"></div>
  <div class="step2"></div>
  <div class="step3"></div>
  <div class="ball"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Was doing it on codepen.io and it didn't highlight the syntax error.